# How to handle a large number of optional parameters

Tags: java, parameters, method-overloading

I am currently developing on a small library allowing to read and write Java .properties files while retaining all the formatting (comments, whitespace, etc.): https://github.com/hupfdule/apron

This library has a `saveTo` method to write the content of such a PropertyFile to a file or an OutputStream. At the moment this `saveTo` allows a Charset to be given as parameter to specify the encoding (if the default UTF-8 should not apply). This leaves me with the following method signatures:

```
saveTo(File)
saveTo(File, Charset)
saveTo(OutputStream)
saveTo(OutputStream, Charset)
```

However there are corresponding `update` and `overwrite` methods so there are actually 6 more methods (update does not allow an OutputStream):

```
update(File)
update(File, Charset)
overwrite(File)
overwrite(File, Charset)
overwrite(OutputStream)
overwrite(OutputStream, Charset)
```

Now I need to introduce another optional Parameter of the enum-type `MissingKeyAction`.

The question is: How to change the method signatures to allow, but not require the optional parameters.

I see the following approaches at the moment:

1. Provide only some parameter-combinations.
   This is similar to e.g. [`JOptionPane#showConfirmDialog(Component parentComponent, Object message, String title, int optionType, int messageType, Icon icon)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showConfirmDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon)) where I need to provide `title`, `optionType` and `messageType` when I actually only want to provide an icon.
2. Specify an overloaded method for each combination of optional parameters.
3. Introduce a new parameter object `Options` to encapsulate all optional parameters and only provide a method with and without such an `Options` parameter.

The 1st approach is not user friendly in my opinion as the consumer of the API needs to specify some parameter values even though he would like to just use the default for them.

The 2nd approach requires a lot of tedious work for specifying all method combinations and I would end up with lots of overloaded methods. This would get even worse if I need to introduce another parameter!

The 3rd approach seems to be the best in my opinion as it does not clutter the interface, allows the API user to provide only the Options where he does not want to rely on the default and it is even upward compatible as I do not need to change the method signatures when I need to add another optional parameter in the future.

If I provide a fluent interface for the `Options` class the client code could look something like this:

```
import java.io.File;
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

public class TestApron {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Options apronOptions= Options.create()
      .with(UTF_8)
      .with(MissingKeyAction.DELETE);
    final PropertyFile propertyFile= new PropertyFile();
    propertyFile.setValue("myKey", "myValue");
    propertyFile.saveTo(new File("someFile.properties"), apronOptions);
  }
}
```

As I already mentioned above I consider this new `Options` parameter as the best solution and am willing to implement this.

However I want to hear some other opinions on that topic and if there are even some other possibilities for addressing this problem I haven't thought of yet.

Comment: Is it actually the case that behaviour such as "reaction to a missing key" should affect only this one save action and might afterwards be entirely different - or is this something that you'd probably want to work consistently during te life time of the object? If so, there's no reason why this has to be an option to the `saveTo` method - it could simply be a setter on the `propertyObject`.

Comment: @KilianFoth It is only relevant to the `saveTo` and `update` operations, but not the current PropertyFile object. The meaning is how to handle key-value-pairs that exist in this object, but not in the .properties file that is updated via `saveTo` or `update`. The possible actions would be COMMENT_OUT (in the written file), DELETE (from the written file) or NOTHING (leave them in the written file).

Comment: Have you considered only using a "saveTo" method, with an enumerator parameter telling it what to do in case of existing file?  Such as saveTo(WhenExisting.Override, theFile)?  You'd simply have combinations of the one method at that point.

Comment: @Neil I like the idea. I will take it into account. This would allow me to make the `update` and `overwrite` methods private. There is only one (small) drawback. I am not able to throw an Exception if the user explicitly wants to update a file, but that file is missing. I could tackle this by adding an enum value like WhenExisting.OnlyUpdate, but that could be a bit too complicated in contrast to just calling `update`. But the idea is good and I like the fluent naming. I should consider this naming style for MissingKeyAction, too.

Comment: Well I didn't mean exactly making the other methods private, but removing them entirely.  Make everything filter to a single private method with all options available (default or otherwise).  Then if anything, break that method into bite-sized pieces so it doesn't get all cluttered.  Food for thought anyway.

Comment: *Builder* design pattern is often recommended as a healthier alternative to telescoping constructors.

Comment: @Neil Thank you. I will think over it. Making `update` and `overwrite` private or removing them is the same from the viewpoint of the user. Therefore both approaches could be used. However I will have to think over what has the best readability.

Comment: @NickAlexeev Actually the above mentioned methods are normal methods, not constructors. However, you are right and my proposal of the `Options` is actually a Builder approach. (In fact is combines the Builder and the built object into one class, since I do not need immutability, but the better readability, usability and robustness to future changes are there).

Comment: @radlan I would make the `Charset` an instance property of the PropertyListReader (or whatever you call it), that's configured once in the initialization, and then implied for every call to its methods.

Comment: @Alexander That actually already is the case. However, the PropertyFile class provides the above mentioned `save`, `update` and `overwrite` methods (that themselves use the `PropertyFileWriter` and they need to be able to specify the Charset.

Comment: @radlan I don't think I would put `save`, `update`, `overwrite` methods on `PropertyFile`. I would keep them on `PropertyFileWriter`, so that the `PropertyFile` class remains focused on getting and setting properties within the file.

Comment: @Alexander I know what you mean. But this was a sensible decision. The `PropertyFile` should be very easy to use. The `PropertyFileReader` and `PropertyFileWriter` are still there to use, but are not as handy. Especially the `update` method is not applicable to the `PropertyFileWriter` and then I would need yet another class, just to extract those methods out of `PropertyFile`. If you are interested, look at those methods: https://github.com/hupfdule/apron/blob/0a5dcfefd17a5f89eb02b685d72bc63ac1f4c777/src/main/java/de/poiu/apron/PropertyFile.java#L600-L652

Comment: @radlan Gluing multiple classes together doesn't make them easier to use. For one, your `PropertyFile` has actually very little to do with files, apart from the fact that it could be serialized to a file, but that could be said about pretty much any data type. The in-memory representation of `PropertyFile` objects is simply a linked hashmap, with no connection to any particular resource on disk. Why is `update` not applicable to PFW?

Comment: About "Why is `update` not applicable to PFW?": This is a Writer class in the same sense of BufferedWriter, PrintWriter, etc. They have a state and can be opened, closed, etc. An update method doesn't fit into this class. The `PropertyFile` class provides `update`, `overwrite` and `saveTo` as well as some `from` methods for easy creation of a `PropertyFile` from an actual file and also writing to an actual file. It does this in the same sense as the `java.util.Properties` class provides methods to load and write its properties from/to a file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439574/whats-the-best-way-to-refactor-a-method-that-has-too-many-6-parameters